# Encoding process.startinfo.arguments wrong

Tags: c#, encoding

I assumed that this is the same problem I am having [Encoding of Process.StartInfo.Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994568/encoding-of-process-startinfo-arguments). But it does not seem so (correct me if I am wrong, though).

I am starting an external process from my application and I am passing a path as argument. Now if the path has special characters (german umlauts in my case). The external application fails, since it gets a different character. The string which is given is correctly displayed in VS2010 debugger.

I created a ConsoleApplication like this to verify, and call it instead of the external application:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    }
```

The output will be shown in my main application and even here the special character is wrong (instead of Ü I get š).

Comment: Command line arguments are Unicode.  Clearly the app your are trying to start is converting them to an 8-bit encoding.  Anything is possible, contact the owner for support.

Comment: Is the args argument for a C# console application also internally converted to 8-bit or why am I experiencing this problem?